# adding a javascript function valuie to a href link

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, geolocation

i have the following javascript function

```
   <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // Wait for device API libraries to load
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // device APIs are available
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
        //     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
        /     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess);
        }

    // onSuccess Geolocation
    //
    function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
        element.innerHTML =  + position.coords.latitude  + ',' + position.coords.longitude;
    }

    // onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
  function onError(error) {
      alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
           'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
//   }

        </script>
```

i need to add the gelocation element value which is a long/lat eg "-27.49256565,153.095735" to the hyper link in my jquery mobile list

```
    $("#homePage").live("pageshow", function() {
                        console.log("Getting remote list");

                        var s = "";
                        s+= "<li><a href='bus1.html?coords='> bus 1 locator</a></li>";
                        s+= "<li><a href='bus2.html?coords='> Bus 2 locator </a></li>";
                        s+= "<li><a href='bus3.html?coords='> Bus3 locator </a></li>";
                        $("#home").html(s);
                        $("#home").listview("refresh");

                        });
```

the above href code works perfectly however i needs the values geolocation element to populate into the value for coords= so the coords are dynamic.

simply put what changes do i need to the above line of code so the coords= value is dynamically populated from the function

i need to have the geolocation value dynamically load to the value coords= appended to the a href

i have spent hours on this and i know i am very close but not there

any assistance will be greatly appreciated

Comment: It's unclear how your two snippets of code fit together. You say you are very close but the few code you show us is actually far from achieving what you're describing. Can you show a little bit more code and maybe tell us what doesn't work and what does?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to look at the query field in the [document.location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils/search) possibilities and then use something like this:

```
function onSuccess(position) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation'); // I assume this is the <a>-element that has to get the URL with that specific coordinates
    element.setAttribute('href', 
        '<your base url>?' + 'coordx=' + position.x + 
        '&coordy=' + position.y);                         // I assume you want your URL set here.
}
```

Retrieving the values is quite easy too, with the help of some openly available code:

```
function getURLParam (str, sVar) {
    return decodeURI(str.replace(new RegExp("^(?:.*[&\\?]" + encodeURI(sVar).replace(/[\.\+\*]/g, "\\$&") + "(?:\\=([^&]*))?)?.*$", "i"), "$1"));
} // this can be found (edited) at MDN (Mozilla Developers Network)

var coordx = getURLParam(window.location.search, 'coordx');
var coordy = getURLParam(window.location.search, 'coordy');
```

Using this you can get your variables in and out of the url, which I thought to be your problem. If it is not, please make your question a bit more specific, and be more clear about your problem.

Comment: Hi,  



i have the location stuff sorted, ALL i need to do is pass the long/lat values that the jgeolocation avascript code outputs to append to the url in the jquery mobile list items i have created

i do not need to specify individual long / lat values as the geolocation javascript code i am using outputs them as a combined single value

the following code <p id="geolocation"> outputs the value i need i just need to know the syntax to populate that value appended to the href="...?coord="

Comment: Also for further clarification my page as multiple buttons not just one so my preference is to be able to reference to long/lat variable determined form the javascript code at the each of the buttons rather than in the javascript itself as the value determined wby the javascript code weach time the app page loads will be used across multiple buttons on the page